# How to move a subtree between trees in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, types, functional-programming

For two multi-way trees, t1 and t2, defined using

```
type Forest a = [Tree a]
data Tree a   = Node {
        rootLabel :: a,     
        subForest :: Forest a
    }
```

how can I write a function that will remove a subtree from t1 and insert it at a given node in t2?

I imagine the signature would look something like

```
moveSubTree :: ((Tree x a) x (Tree x a)) -> (Tree x Tree)
```

i.e. it takes a tree and parent node defining a subtree to be removed, and a second tree and node that defines the point at which to insert the original subtree.

Separate functions to remove and then add the subtree could be composed if necessary.

Comment: What is `x`? Also, Haskell has no pointers. A Tree value is just a Tree, not a subtree of anything. You need to provide some way to obtain a subtree from a tree, like path (a list of indices).

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "...insert it at a given depth in t2" -- There may be several points in the tree at any given depth, which one do you want to move it to?

Comment: That makes sense - I should have put "insert it at a given node in t2". I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make edits and reads "at a path" in a tree.

```
data Dir    = L | R
type Path   = [Dir]
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

read :: Path -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
read []     t = t
read (s:ss) t = case t of
  Leaf       -> Nothing
  Node a l r -> case s of
    L -> read ss l
    R -> read ss r

edit :: Path -> (Tree a -> Tree a) -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
edit []     f t = Just (f t)
edit (s:ss) f t = case t of
  Leaf       -> Nothing
  Node a l r -> case s of
    L -> do
      l' <- edit ss f l
      return (Node a l' r)
    R -> do
      r' <- edit ss f r
      return (Node a l r')
```

And then using this tool you can "copy and paste" subtrees from one path to another

```
cnp :: Path -> Path -> Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
cnp readPath writePath t = do
  subtree <- read readPath t
  edit writePath (const subtree) t
```

Interestingly, "subtree at path" forms a `Lens` which subsumes the common structure between these two operations.

Comment: A minor nitpick, TS wanted a multiway tree, not binary.

Comment: True. This idea generalizes to multi-way trees by using `type Path = [Int]` and noting that paths can "miss" both by being too long and by referencing a non-existent subtree.